# How to solve the differences in ls command behavior across different file system types?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ls, ubifs

My work environment is: Linux 3.2.0,ARMV7L,GNU/Linux; CPU is AM335x.

**Background:**

1.The original file system in flash was UBIFS, but due to some reasons that I have not yet found, it was prone to corruption, so I replaced the file system format with YAFFS2.

2.In a certain folder, a file is generated every second. I need to periodically check the remaining space in flash to ensure that the space occupied by this folder does not exceed 50%. When it exceeds 50%, I need to delete the earliest file in the folder until the remaining space is greater than 50%.

3.I wrote a shell script to implement the above function, which uses `ls -rt**`

```
#!/bin/sh

folder_path="/path/to/folder"
min_space_percent=50

while true
do
    free_space=$(df -k | grep "/dev/mtdblock" | awk '{print $4}')
    oldest_file=$(ls -rt $folder_path | head -n 1)
    oldest_file_path="$folder_path/$oldest_file"
    
    if [ $free_space -gt $min_space_percent ]
    then
        rm $oldest_file_path
    else
        break
    fi
    
done
```

When I execute this script, I encounter an issue where RS-485 cannot communicate properly.

After investigation, I found that when there are a large number of files in the folder, more than a thousand, executing `ls -rt` will cause this issue.

But the key point is that this issue occurs on the YAFFS2 file system, while it does not occur on the UBIFS file system.

**My solution:**

1.I asked ChatGPT and it said: If the performance of the file system is poor, processing a large number of files may cause the system to respond slowly, the CPU usage rate to be high, and thus cause 485 communication anomalies.

2.So I rewrote a program to find the earliest created file in the folder. After each search, there is a 2ms delay to reduce resource usage. Test results: When the number of files is around 5000, there is no problem as before. However, when the number of files is larger, it still affects 485 communication.

```
c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat file_stat;
    time_t earliest_time = time(NULL);
    char *earliest_file = NULL;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <directory>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    dir = opendir(argv[1]);
    if (dir == NULL) {
        perror("opendir");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        char *filename = entry->d_name;
        char filepath[1024];
        sprintf(filepath, "%s/%s", argv[1], filename);

        if (stat(filepath, &file_stat) == -1) {
            perror("stat");
            continue;
        }

        if (file_stat.st_mtime < earliest_time) {
            earliest_time = file_stat.st_mtime;
            earliest_file = filename;
        }
        usleep(2000);
    }

    printf("Earliest file: %s\n", earliest_file);

    closedir(dir);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**My doubts:**

1. What are the specific reasons for the differences in the ls command between the YAFFS2 and UBIFS file systems?
2. How to better solve this problem?

Comment: My question: Do the secretive _485 communication anomalies_ occur with a single run of your C program already, or only with repeated runs?

Comment: The 485 communication anomalies occur with a single run. For example, the 485 communication anomalies occur when I execute the "ls" command or my C program in a folder with a large number of files.